# IO Exception writing serializable object? passing images arraylist

Tags: object, runtime-error, parcelable, serializable

class Selected_img_layout:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Selected_img_layout.this, ImagSlider.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("image_data", spacecrafts);
                i.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(i);
```

class ImagSlider:

```
 Bundle bundleobject = getIntent().getExtras();
 spacecrafts = (ArrayList<Spacecraft>) bundleobject.getSerializable("image_data");
```

class Spacecraft:

```
public class Spacecraft implements Serializable {
        Uri uri;

        public Spacecraft() {
        }

        public Spacecraft(String name, Uri uri) {
            this.name = name;
            this.uri = uri;
        }

        public Uri getUri() {
            return uri;
        }

        public void setUri(Uri uri) {
            this.uri = uri;
        }
     }
```

Error

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.example.letsgo.mypdfconverter.Spacecraft)
```

Comment: Please post your complete `Spacecraft` class. What you've posted couldn't possibly compile.

Answer (score 0):

> replace this:

```
 public Spacecraft(String name, Uri uri) {
            this.name = name;
            this.uri = uri;
        }
```

> with:

```
 public Spacecraft( Uri uri) {
            this.uri = uri;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code:
**Intent i = new Intent(Selected_img_layout.this, ImagSlider.class);
                i.putExtras("image_data",spacecrafts);
                startActivity(i);**

Try This to get Your data in another activity

**Spacecraft spaceCraft =(Spacecraft)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("image_data")**

Comment: cant pass an arraylist(gallary selected images ) in putextras

Comment: spacecrafts is Object of Spacecraft  and it Extends Serializable interface so you can pass it because it is in serializable formate